# (Calc II) Divergence of cos(x) as x approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I was doing a l'hopital's problem that ended with needing to compute the limit of cos(x) as x approaches infinity, which I know diverges. However, I was doing some thinking, and realized that cos(x) can be represented by its taylor expansion as the sum from n=0 to infinity of (-1)^n*((x)^2n)/((2n)!) , which has a radius of convergence of infinity, and therefore converges for every x...
It makes sense to me intuitively why cos(x) doesn't converge at infinity, but why do these two claims seem to contradict?

Comment: I am not sure wheter I fully understand your problem, but keep in mind that beeing defined for alle real numbers does not imply any behaviour "at infinity'. The identity also is defined for all real numbers, it is also a power series with infinite radius of convergence, but it has no limit towards infinity

Comment: The infinite radius of convergence tells us that the power series converges for all $x$ (and it's actually Taylor's theorem that tells us that the function it converges to is $\cos(x)$). These theorems don't stipulate that these functions must have a limit as $x \to \infty$, so I don't really understand where this contradiction is supposed to lie.

Comment: Why do you think those are contradictory? The taylor series is $\cos x$ for a specific $x$ and converges as $n\to \infty$ but $x$ just stays there being $x$.  $\cos x$ refuses to converge as $x$ moves to infinity and $x$ *doesn't* stay there being $x$.

Comment: Infinite sums and limits don't commute.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main point of misunderstanding is in what a limit is:

When we talk about $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$, what we are talking about is in essence a process where you keep on taking $x$ bigger and bigger (i.e. approaching infinity) and seeing what happens with the values of $\cos x$, and seeing if it settles down and approaches (i.e. converges to) a point. As you correctly point out, this limit diverges, which means that if we keep taking bigger values of $x$, the value of $\cos x$ never stabilizes to a specific value (it oscillates in this case). If you know the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, this would be a really valuable place to check to make sure that this intuitive definition aligns with your understanding of the formal one.

The key here is that this says nothing about any one specific value of $\cos x$ for a specific $x$, it's discussing a process where we keep on considering bigger and bigger $x$ and see if the values of $\cos x$ converge.

On the other hand, when we talk about $\cos x$ having a power series with a radius of convergence being infinity, it means that for any $x$, the infinite series $\cos x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ converges and therefore is a valid way to think about/calculate $\cos x$. If we had a smaller radius of convergence, this would tell us that the power series representation would only work for certain values of $x$ and we wouldn't be able to use it in every case.

So, the power series works for any $x$, including $x$ arbitrarily big, but it works to give the value of $\cos x$ for *any specific value of $x$*, which isn't the same as asking about the whole limit process above. This a case where the word "convergence/divergence" are doubling up, one to talk about the power series representation for a specific value of $x$, and one to talk about the limiting process as you consider different values of $x$.